# How to make a string from Array in plpgsql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, string-constant

I've got a result from my function

```
EXECUTE format('SELECT ARRAY (SELECT tvmid from "%s".tvmtable order by tvmid)', operatorName) INTO tvms;
```

that gives mi array of tvms in format {1,2,3}. I need it to have a String divided with , so I'm trying like

```
SELECT ARRAY_TO_STRING(tvms, ",") INTO res;
```

but when I'm executing my function I got error

```
ERROR:  column "," does not exist
```

If it helps here is my whole function

```
create or replace function getTVMList(operatorName varchar)
returns varchar as $$
declare
tvms varchar[];
res varchar;
begin
EXECUTE format('SELECT ARRAY (SELECT tvmid from "%s".tvmtable order by tvmid)', operatorName) INTO tvms;
SELECT ARRAY_TO_STRING(tvms, ",") INTO res;
return res;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Comment: In this case, the aggregate function `string_agg` can ve used too. It will be faster, simpler and more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double quotes reference a column name.

You have to put the comma into single quotes instead of double quotes: `','`

```
 SELECT ARRAY_TO_STRING(tvms, ',') INTO res;
```